# Does LightningChart Shared Axis functionality support stacking 2 line series on top of each other with multiple Y Axes and a shared X Axis?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have a requirement to create stacked Line Charts on top of each other. Basically I want to create 2 Y axes and have them share a common X axis. These two Y axes should be stacked on top of each other.

I am aware of an option for ChartXY to add axes (https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.0/classes/ChartXY.html#addAxisY) but it seems that for adding Y axes the default arguments would be either on left or right side. Is there a way to change this to top or bottom? Would appreciate any help or any other way to achieve this through LightningCharts.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support for stacking several Y axes above each other in 1 chart.

Currently this use case is realized by making several charts, synchronizing their X axes and having only 1 of the X axes visible. For example https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0028-multiChannelLineProgressiveOwnAxes.html?isList=false